# Suspected a person had an affair with the professor

Tags: ethics, teaching-assistant, cheating

I was a TA for a summer course, and a student in the class somehow managed to get nearly perfect score on all the assignments/midterms/final exam.

I am suspecting that the person had an affair with the Professor, as given the persons capabilities they should be around average. Also, the professor would consistently look at that person in an awkward way.

What should I do? I don't have proof.

Initially I thought I should mind my own business, whatever, I mean there's no point in bringing it up..? it won't change anything for the better, just make two people miserable; though for some reason it's stuck in my head, I want to know what someone else would do in such circumstances

Comment: It seems much more likely to me that you've misjudged this student's abilities.  You don't seem to have nearly enough evidence here to jump to any wrongdoing at all, let alone an affair.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Well I have my reasons for suspecting it, I generally don't jump to conclusions unless It's completely out of the norm. I did not want to bring up the details as it isn't completely appropriate/relevant for asking the question.
I personally appreciate Paul's answer as it's along my train of thought, and confirms I did think about this correctly,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suspect, you should just let it go. I think it is indeed reasonable for the situation to prey on your mind, but it is beyond your power to really do anything positive or negative, and, as you say, any attempt to do so would probably just create unpleasantness without being effective.

The potential "victims" of the situation (apart from the student, we may argue... even if it is not clear in the moment) are other students, if any of them get worse grades due to the situation, or if they come to suspect that there's some hanky-panky going on, which would be suspected to influence grades. At the very least, the principle that anything distracting from the immediate goals of a class is undesirable... means that an affair between a student and teacher is bad in that sense.

But, for you, just let it go, just as for most purposes we must just "let go" our disquiet with bad news on television. Yes, _if_possible_, we should not fail to act to improve things. But our plausible scope of action is not global, and maybe not even too much about every "local" thing.

Comment: And, of course, it could be that the prof is merely "fixated on" or "infatuated with" the student, and is behaving badly... This would be essentially impossible to document, and possibly indistinguishable from the side effects and biases of "having an affair".